# Command not found ZSH Error after updating zshrc file

Tags: macos, zshrc

I recently updated some applications and now it is giving me error when I open any new tab in teminal.
Error it is giving:

> `/Users/priti/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh:28: command not found:
>   whoami /Users/priti/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:10:
>   command not found: uname
>   /Users/priti/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:14: command not
>   found: uname getent:4: command not found: grep`

I am sure something is wrong with the updated `zshrc` file, but I am not able to figure out what exactly the problem in that.

Problems I have faced till now are `vi` and `grep`command not working.For both output is `command not found`.

Thanks in advance for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling zsh solved the problem.

Some steps I followed after `brew update` might have caused this problem.